# How to by pass Cube dev pagination limited to 50000 results

Tags: sql, cube

We use Jupyter on top of Cube dev through the SQL access.
It seems that cube limits the number of results to 50000 which make sens for BI/Analytics usage but for data science we need to retrieve more data.
There is an offset with the REST API but i don't find anything like this for SQL access
Thanks for your help

I tried to set an offset in the SQL Query

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Read also [ask].